# How can I make the number input only accept a certain ammount of charaters?

Tags: html

I am having people enter their id for a giveaway. All ids are 17 characters long.

How can I make it so that the number of numbers they post have to be 17 characters long?

example: id number is 76561197969408686

the input field can only accept 17 number long ids

EDIT: If you have been having the same problem with chrome that I have, please see my answer below

Comment: You should not use number input (`<input type=number>`) for identifiers even if they consist of digits only. HTML5 CR explicitly warns about this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern-attribute, which gives you a nice output:

```
<input pattern="[0-9]{17}" required title="17 characters are needed">
```

In Javascript, you can make the Check like this:

```
var input = getElementById("yourID").value;
if( input.match(/^[0-9]{17}$/) != NULL){
    //correct
}
```

In php, it should work this way:

```
if( preg_match("^[0-9]{17}$", $_POST['userid']) === 1){
    //correct
}else{
     die ('please add your id');
}
```

Comment: The question said number input, not text input. The maxlength attribute does not apply to number inputs.

Comment: @Quentin: I modified the answer. The pattern-attribute exists for number-inputs.

Comment: Do you think you can do a PHP or Javascript if statement that says: `if ($_POST['item'] charaters != 17 { die ('please add you id')}` I don't know what I would put in place of characters though...

Comment: @user259345 I added the examples for JS and php

Comment: maybe .length to check to see how long the characters are?

Comment: @user259345 Yes, using the length is also possible, but it doesn't check if it really only consits out of numbers. Therefore I would recommend using a regular expression

Comment: do you know why this works in firefox but not chrome?

Comment: Do you have the latest Version? FF should support the pattern-attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I do have the latest version, I made my own code to fix it. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have the same problem with Chrome that I do, use this block of code

```
if (strlen($_POST['userid']) > 17) {
        die ('the user id has to be 17 characters long');
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['userid']) < 17) {
    die ('the user id has to be 17 characters long');
    }
```

Replace the 17 with the number of characters you want the input to accept

Answer (score -1):

[min and max](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-max)

```
min="1000000000000000" max="9999999999999999"
```

Comment: Although bear in mind that it doesn't stop someone just typing in a larger value rather than using the arrows.

Comment: @Jeepstone — It [stops them submitting the form](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/8f7d2462-9be5-4d3b-b541-38a0fa5d9208/6c777e9340b84f5368de7f0cb3870f7c) though.

Comment: True. Funnily, enough I'd been working on a form that changed behaviour depending on the value of a number field and as a result, you could enter a large value (which would then break the form) and fell outside of the limits set.

Comment: This disallows any id with a leading 0. And it allows more than 17 digits when leading zeros are used.